# StretchDIBits doesnt resize the image

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I am testing my application on Windows Server 2012 R2. It works on every other (non-server OS), however while I am testing it on here, it doesnt resize the image to the specified size. The return from the `StretchDIBits` calls is exactly the amount of scan lines specified in the input buffer, where as the expected output is not returned.

Here is my code:

```
SetStretchBltMode(resized_environment, HALFTONE);
StretchDIBits(resized_environment, 0, 0, output_x_axis, output_y_axis, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, 
   bitmap_data, (BITMAPINFO *) &bitmap_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

What could be a probable cause of this? As I said, it works on every OS aside from this one.

Comment: Anything different about that machine? Headless, remote desktop, etc?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Yes, its a remote desktop! Would this affect it? And how so?

Comment: What exactly *are* you getting that's different from what's expected?

Comment: @SteveFriedl I am getting an image of the exact same dimensions as the original. It is not being resized.

Comment: What’s the return value from StretchDIBits ?

Comment: @SteveFriedl 866 (the number of scan lines (height in px) in the image), but I am trying to resize it to 600 and the width to 800.

Comment: Have you verified that `output_y_axis` is actually set to 600? How is that calculated?

Comment: As @JonathanPotter suggests, I think we need to see more code. Please be sure to check the return value of *every* function involved in the execution path.

Comment: Have you considered using the [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) instead. If nothing else, it allows you to be much more specific about the re-sampling algorithm, producing results with generally higher quality. See [How to Scale a Bitmap Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-bitmapsources-howto-scale) for sample code.